# What is the best way of java and javascript interaction?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, interaction

Excuse my lack of knowledge in many fundamental areas, but I am just learning how to create applets in java and how to allow interaction between the applet and the web page (javascript).

At the moment I have an applet with an init() and method1(). method1() just returns a string.

The applet is loaded on a web page and in javascript I literally reference the function:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Applet</title>
<script>
function hello() {

    result = document.wplayer.method1();
    alert(result);

}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<applet  code = "player.Player" name = "wplayer" archive = "player.jar" width = "600"     height = "400">

</applet>

<button onClick="hello();">Interact with app</button>
```

method1() just returns a string ("blah blah blah");

My question is, is this a safe way to do it and is it the most compatible?

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this a safe way to do it and is it the most compatible?

It's only as safe as the client is safe, so you should assume that the client may edit/forge/hack, etc.

If you meant *safe* in the other sense - not causing conflict - use an *Object* as your namespace in *JavaScript* and have everything kept within that *Object*. This way you are much less likely to have trouble with any conflicting variable names elsewhere on a page. You may also want to use *unobtrusive JavaScript*, to keep your script and *HTML* independent of each other.

Currently, your function `hello` is in the global namespace, and creates a global `result`, which could cause conflicts.

Assuming that the client has an up-to-date copy of *Java* and plugins enabled, you only really need to worry about the same compatibility issues as when writing any normal *JavaScript* for any browser.

Comment: As a side note, your _HTML_ makes me cry D: Is there reasoning behind your whitespacing?

Comment: Thanks paul. Sorry about the whitespace, It happened when I pasted the code over.

Comment: I willy definitely start practising unobtrusive javascript and storing things in objects. That way, this removes global hello() and global result(). 

Thanks a lot.